# How to Find a substring in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way in Oracle to find out a substring by giving the column name and the sub-string which I want to find. There is no definite pattern to decide that where the sub-string would lie in the string.

For example:
contains([Device],"IPHONE")

DEVICE --- Column Name
IPHONE --- Sub-string to be found

Result should be the sub-string itself, not its position.

Comment: use `like '%IPHONE%'` to check if a field `contains IPHONE`

Comment: use LIKE with wildcards % - also look up REGEX pattern matching if you want something more complicated.

Comment: Are you using `Oracle TEXT`?